# Workaround for outer join with an IN operator in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I am using Oracle SQL, so outer joins have the nice (+) syntax. I should warn you that I am not allowed to redesign the database; I work for a large organization.

Here are some example tables:

```
People
PersonID   Name
1          Elmo
2          Oscar
3          Chris

Attribute
PersonID   Attribute
1          Happy
1          Muppet
1          Popular
2          Grouchy
2          Muppet
2          Popular
3          Programmer
```

I want a list of people and I want to know whether we have knowledge of them being happy or grouchy. The following is the output I want:

```
Name       Mood
Elmo       Happy
Oscar      Grouchy
Chris
```

So here is the query I thought I would use:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p, Attributes a
WHERE p.PersonID = a.PersonID (+)
AND ( a.Attribute (+) = 'Happy'
   OR a.Attribute (+) = 'Grouchy' )
```

(Perhaps I would have to put "OR a.Attribute IS NULL" or something.)

But in fact I'm not allowed to use OR inside an outer join at all! What should I actually do instead?

Comment: Your query works just fine for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14c50/1

Comment: @mellamokb That is fairly awesome, but perhaps that is not the same version as I am using. Here is my error: Exception: DBD, ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
State: N/A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, why can't you use proper `OUTER JOIN`s?, you can use them in Oracle without having to do the implicit joins with the `(+)` syntax. As for your problem, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID AND a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy')
```

Comment: @ChrisCunningham - And its throwing that error with the query above?. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: This does not work. Yours will not return Chris, since the Attribute that will come back on the Outer Join will be "Programmer" -- not null, not Happy, and not Grouchy.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham - Really?, did you tried it first?, cause I'm fairly sure that it works

Comment: Chris will be paired with Programmer, so his attribute is neither Happy nor Grouchy. Yes I tried it.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham You should have not changed Lamaks query - outer join filtering should be done within ON clause.

Comment: Oops. @Nikola I don't know how I managed to misread what he wrote and translate it into something wrong... accepting this answer now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

If you really know the Oracel SQL syntax for a "proper" Oracle database, you could also do this...

```
SELECT p.Name,
       a.Attribute
  FROM people p,
       (SELECT PersonID,
               Attribute
          FROM attributes
              WHERE Attribute = 'Happy'
              OR Attribute = 'Grouchy') a
  WHERE p.personid = a.personid(+)
```

The point being that ANSI vs Oracle syntax is a ridiculous comment. Oracle supports both, you whichever is easier/better/manageable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question. To avoid the error ORA-01719, I changed everything to "proper" joins at the advice of @Lamak, and then went with this solution:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT PersonID, Attribute
                  FROM Attributes
                  WHERE Attribute = 'Happy' OR Attribute = 'Grouchy') a
ON (p.PersonID = a.PersonID)
```