# ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN

Tags: sql, oracle

While running my query I'm getting an error:

> ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
>   01719. 00000 -  "outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN"
>
> Cause:    An outer join appears in an or clause.
>
> Action:   If A and B are predicates, to get the effect of (A(+) or B),
>              try (select where (A(+) and not B)) union all (select where (B))

I'm getting this error due to my AND Or conditions under where clause which i have defined under last.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rp.rp_record_id,
                rp.rate_profile_name,
                rph.rate_type,
                rph.charge_code,
                rph.transport_mode,
                rph.place_of_receipt_code,
                rph.origin_type,
                rph.destination_type
  FROM rate_profile rp,
       rate_profile_header rph,
       partner_charge_profile pcp,
       partner,
       commodity_codes com,
       offices,
       partner_relationships pr,
       company_partners cp,
       employee e
 WHERE        rp.rp_record_id = rph.rp_record_id
          AND pcp.partner_id = partner.partner_id
          AND rph.commcode_record_id = com.cc_record_id(+)
          AND pcp.company_id = offices.company_id
          AND offices.office_type = 'T'
          AND partner.partner_id = pr.partner_id(+)
          AND pr.employee_no = e.employee_no
          AND partner.partner_id = cp.partner_id
          AND cp.company_id = '&CompanyID'
          AND cp.company_id = pcp.company_id
          AND cp.company_id(+) = pr.company_id
          AND pcp.charge_code = rph.charge_code
          AND pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
          AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id
          AND (    ('&psRate_type') = 'SEL'
               AND (    rph.rate_type = 'SEL'
                    AND pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
                    AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id))
       OR (    ('&psRate_type') = 'BUY'
           AND (    rph.rate_type = 'BUY'
                AND pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R'
                AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id))
       OR (    ('&psRate_type') = 'All'
           AND (   (    rph.rate_type = 'SEL'
                    AND pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
                    AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)
                OR (    (rph.rate_type = 'BUY')
                    AND pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R'
                    AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)))
```

Please suggest

Comment: I would suggest to change to the new JOIN syntax

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can i use this AND (    ('&psRate_type') = 'SEL'
               AND (    rph.rate_type = 'SEL'
                    AND pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
                    AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id))
       OR (    ('&psRate_type') = 'BUY'
           AND (    rph.rate_type = 'BUY'
                AND pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R'
                AND rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id))   in any other way?

Comment: Have a look at the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758526/workaround-for-outer-join-with-an-in-operator-in-oracle and start using new JOIN syntax.

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to use "modern" explicit `LEFT JOIN` syntax rather than the proprietary `(+)` operator

Comment: Thanks Sudipta and no_name. It's working..

Comment: You have both `cp.company_id = '&CompanyID'` and `cp.company_id(+) = pr.company_id`, so there isn't actually an outer join to `company_partners`. The same thing goes for your `pr` joins (`partner.partner_id = pr.partner_id(+)` but `pr.employee_no = e.employee_no`). Also I'd be concerned about the unbracketed `OR` predicates defeating the join conditions - I suspect they should all be contained within one `AND` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OR` condition referred to in the outer join error message is in the `'&psRate_type'` filter section, which I don't think you intended to be part of the join. If you bracket all of those conditions inside an `AND` predicate, the error will go away:

```
select distinct
       rp.rp_record_id
     , rp.rate_profile_name
     , rph.rate_type
     , rph.charge_code
     , rph.transport_mode
     , rph.place_of_receipt_code
     , rph.origin_type
     , rph.destination_type
from   rate_profile           rp
     , rate_profile_header    rph
     , partner_charge_profile pcp
     , partner
     , commodity_codes        com
     , offices
     , partner_relationships  pr
     , company_partners       cp
     , employee               e
where  rp.rp_record_id = rph.rp_record_id
and    pcp.partner_id = partner.partner_id
and    com.cc_record_id (+) = rph.commcode_record_id
and    pcp.company_id = offices.company_id
and    offices.office_type = 'T'
and    pr.partner_id (+) = partner.partner_id
and    pr.employee_no = e.employee_no
and    partner.partner_id = cp.partner_id
and    cp.company_id = '&CompanyID'
and    cp.company_id = pcp.company_id
and    cp.company_id (+) = pr.company_id
and    pcp.charge_code = rph.charge_code
and    pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
and    rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id
-- Added brackets below:
and    (    ('&psRate_type' = 'SEL' and rph.rate_type = 'SEL' and pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id)
        or  ('&psRate_type' = 'BUY' and rph.rate_type = 'BUY' and pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)
        or  ('&psRate_type' = 'All'
             and (    (rph.rate_type = 'SEL' and pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)
                  or  (rph.rate_type = 'BUY' and pcp.cost_calculation_method   = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id))
            )
       );
```

However, `company_partners` can't actually be an outer join, because `cp.company_id = '&CompanyID'`. The same thing goes for `partner_relationships`, because `pr.employee_no = e.employee_no`. The only real outer join is to `commodity_codes`, which is not used in the query anyway and can be removed without affecting the result.

With this taken into account, I get the following as the ANSI version:

```
select distinct
       rp.rp_record_id
     , rp.rate_profile_name
     , rph.rate_type
     , rph.charge_code
     , rph.transport_mode
     , rph.place_of_receipt_code
     , rph.origin_type
     , rph.destination_type
from   company_partners cp
       join partner_relationships  pr
            on  pr.company_id = cp.company_id
            and pr.partner_id = cp.partner_id
       /*join partner  -- not needed if pr.partner_id is a FK to partner
            on  partner.partner_id = pr.partner_id*/
       join partner_charge_profile pcp
            on  pcp.company_id = cp.company_id
            and pcp.partner_id = cp.partner_id
       join rate_profile_header rph
            on  rph.charge_code = pcp.charge_code
            and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.charge_rateprof_record_id
       join rate_profile rp
            on  rp.rp_record_id = rph.rp_record_id
       join employee e
            on  e.employee_no = pr.employee_no
       join offices
            on  offices.company_id = pcp.company_id
       /*left join commodity_codes com  -- not used
            on  com.cc_record_id = rph.commcode_record_id*/
where  cp.company_id = '&CompanyID'
and    pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R'
and    offices.office_type = 'T'
and    (    ('&psRate_type' = 'SEL' and rph.rate_type = 'SEL' and pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R')
        or  ('&psRate_type' = 'BUY' and rph.rate_type = 'BUY' and pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)
        or  ('&psRate_type' = 'All' 
             and (    (rph.rate_type = 'SEL' and pcp.charge_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)
                  or  (rph.rate_type = 'BUY' and pcp.cost_calculation_method = 'R' and rph.rp_record_id = pcp.cost_rateprof_record_id)))
       );
```