# Data issues on SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not able to fetch  data only for the BUY parameter. SEL parameter is working fine. May be an issue with joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    RP.RP_RECORD_ID,
    RP.RATE_PROFILE_NAME, 
    RPH.RATE_TYPE, 
    RPH.CHARGE_CODE, 
    RPH.TRANSPORT_MODE, 
    RPH.PLACE_OF_RECEIPT_CODE, 
    (SELECT CD_DESCRIPTION FROM CODE_DETAIL 
     WHERE CM_CODE ='145' AND CD_CODE = RPH.ORIGIN_TYPE), 
    DECODE(RPH.ORIGIN_TYPE, 'PO', RPH.ORIGIN_PORT_CODE, 'CNT' , ORIGIN_COUNTRY_CODE, 'A', ORIGIN_AREA_CODE, 'CIT', CITY_ORIGIN, 'PV', RPH.ORIGIN_REGION_CODE) ORIGIN,
    RPH.PLACE_OF_DELIVERY_CODE,  
    RPH.CARRIER_CODE, 
    PCP.PARTNER_ID, 
    PARTNER.PARTNER_NAME, 
    COM.COMMODITY_DESCRIPTION, 
    RPH.REMARK, RPH.RPH_RECORD_ID,
    RPH.ORIGIN_TYPE, RPH.DESTINATION_TYPE,
    (SELECT DISTINCT EMP.employee_name                             
     FROM partner PAR, employee EMP, partner_relationships PRE 
     WHERE PARTNER.partner_id = PAR.partner_id 
       AND PAR.partner_id = PRE.partner_id 
       AND PRE.EMPLOYEE_NO = EMP.EMPLOYEE_NO 
       AND PRE.transport_mode = RPH.transport_mode 
       AND (PRE.IMPORT_EXPORT_IND IS NULL OR    -- ' Start of New code by SB on 16-FEB-2010 for WHD136784
            PRE.IMPORT_EXPORT_IND = (CASE 
                                        WHEN (RPH.City_Origin = 'VNSGN' OR rph.origin_country_code ='VN' OR rph.origin_port_code ='VN' OR RPH.origin_port_code = 'VNSGN') 
                                           THEN 'E' 
                                        WHEN (RPH.City_Dest = 'VNSGN' OR RPH.dest_country_code = 'VN' OR RPH.dest_port_code = 'VNSGN' OR  RPH.dest_port_code = 'VNSGN') 
                                           THEN 'I' 
                                        ELSE '' 
                                   END))        --  'End of New code by SB on 16-FEB-2010 for WHD136784
       AND PRE.company_id = CP.company_id 
       AND rownum = 1) salesman,                            --   'End of WHD136784 new code
      RPH.RPH_RECORD_ID, RPH.CURRENCY_CODE 
  FROM
      RATE_PROFILE RP, RATE_PROFILE_HEADER RPH, 
      PARTNER_CHARGE_PROFILE PCP,  PARTNER , 
      COMMODITY_CODES com, OFFICES,  
      company_partners CP 
  WHERE
      RP.RP_RECORD_ID =  RPH.RP_RECORD_ID 
      AND PCP.PARTNER_ID = PARTNER.PARTNER_ID 
      AND RPH.COMMCODE_RECORD_ID = COM.CC_RECORD_ID(+) 
      AND PCP.COMPANY_ID = OFFICES.COMPANY_ID 
      AND OFFICES.OFFICE_TYPE = 'T' 
      AND partner.partner_id = CP.partner_id             
      AND CP.COMPANY_ID = '{?CompanyID}'             
      AND CP.company_id = PCP.company_id 
      AND PCP.charge_code = RPH.Charge_code    
      AND (('&psRate_type') = 'SEL' AND  PCP.charge_calculation_method = 'R' AND RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.CHARGE_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID
      OR
           ('&psRate_type') = 'BUY' AND  PCP.cost_calculation_method = 'R' AND RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.COST_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID)
       )
```

Data is coming for the 'SEL' parameter but for 'BUY' it is fetching 0 records.
I checked the joins everything but unable to figured out what's the problem.
No issue with AND OR condition under where clause.

Please suggest

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to help with when we don't know the kind of data you are working with. Try and create a simple example of your problem instead of just dumping code and asking for suggestions.

Comment: i tried to add the join (RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.CHARGE_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID AND --    'WHD168541 - Stuart - 02/23/2011 - Corrected to handle both 'BUY' and 'SEL' rate types 
RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.COST_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID but still it is not working.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. in the last i'm filtering data through 2 parameters 'SEL' and 'BUY'. Data is coming if i filter it through 'SEL' but no rows are coming for 'BUY' parameters. so I'm facing issues with JOINS condition. If i post the half code then it's difficult for me to show you my join conditions

Comment: Post input data and what results you want to see

Comment: You are inner joining on charge code `PCP.charge_code = RPH.Charge_code`. It looks like the `BUY` rows have something to do with COST instead of CHARGE. Maybe that helps?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Run it without those conditions in your WHERE clause and see what's up with the data. Do you see records that would satisfy your `Buy` condition?

Comment: @fuko there are still bracketing issues, similar to those in [your earlier question about these tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51054553/230471).

Comment: William, Bracket issues is resolved. It's related to joins

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue using below joins conditions:

```
(RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.CHARGE_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID OR RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.COST_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID)
```