# Why can't you use OR or IN with a OUTER JOIN operation?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I use the following query in an Oracle SQL database (inspired by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758526/workaround-for-outer-join-with-an-in-operator-in-oracle)):

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID 
WHERE a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy')
AND p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar')
```

I will get the error:

> ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN

While this should fix it:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID AND a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy') AND p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar')
```

Could anyone explain what is the reason the first version invokes an error? What's the actual difference?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758526/workaround-for-outer-join-with-an-in-operator-in-oracle

Comment: Your first query, if it ran, would be identical to just using an `INNER JOIN` so it's sort of superfluous to try to get that query working as-is. Stick your `a.Attributes IN()` condition in your ON clause and put your `p.Person_Id IN ()` condition in your WHERE clause. This allows the LEFT OUTER JOIN to function as intended (without accidently causing an implicit INNER JOIN) and should allow the query to run.

Comment: Thank you JNevil. Would've accepted if it was an answer.

Comment: I don't see how this query can cause the error mentioned. There is no `+` in the query.

Comment: It seems to work as-is: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01328/7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've defined an inner join there, by the way.

By having a clause against the right hand table, it must meet both criteria.

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID 
WHERE a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy') -- This means that the right side must exist also
AND p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar')
```

Either use INNER JOIN or move this WHERE to the ON clause as an AND

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone explain what is the reason the first version invokes an error?

It is just the way Oracle decided to do it: invoking the error on such use of OUTER JOIN:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4247209685061

> What's the actual difference?

Here I may be able to give you a fuller explanation (I hope)...

OUTER JOIN, in contrast to INNER JOIN, is designed to allow you to select all rows from Table A (in your example table *people*) with corresponding data from Table B joined in the same resulting row, if it exists. That means that OUTER JOIN allows for nonexistent Table B data.

[image]

When you put columns from your table B into WHERE clause, you are making their existence mandatory (they must exist if you are comparing them) thus effectively making your join an INNER JOIN.

[image]

On the other hand, when you wrote the following code:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID AND a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy') AND p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar')
```

it is equivalent as if you've written this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM Attributes
                  WHERE Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy')
                ) a   ON (p.PersonID = a.PersonID)
WHERE p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar')
```

and thus you have resumed using OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

it's just the way Oracle implemented the (+) operator (many years ago): some things do not work with it. Another example is the full outer join (which can only be formulated with the help of a UNION ALL with the (+) operator).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is an inner join, so you might as well write:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p INNER JOIN
     Attributes a
     ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID 
WHERE a.Attribute IN ('Happy','Grouchy') AND
      p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar');
```

Any use of `LEFT JOIN` is undone by the `WHERE` clause, because of the `NULL` value in `a.Attribute`.

If you want a person even with no matches, then you do want a `LEFT JOIN` *and* to move the condition on the second table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Attribute
FROM People p INNER JOIN
     Attributes a
     ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID AND
        a.Attribute IN ('Happy', 'Grouchy')
WHERE p.person_id IN ('Elmo', 'Oscar');
```

Comment: So if I wanted to find a person with no attribute, could I use  "a.Attribute IN ('Happy', 'Grouchy') or a.attribute is null"?