# Oracle Join Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am facing problem on executing oracle sql, the first code example is working when executing, while the second one appeared error ('invalid number') , both supposed to produce the same result. May i ask what is wrong with the second sql? Please guide me on this.

First SQL

```
    select a5.LOTID,COUNT(a5.stephandle) AS STEPHANDLE from LOTFLOW_D a5,

    (select distinct(LOTID),MAX(STEPHANDLE) AS STEPHANDLE from Lotmove_R
    where QTAP_GROUP In ('8685','8686','8687','8688','8689','8533','8532','2534','2533','8684','8690')
    and datadate>sysdate-3
    and priority<=5
    and SUBPLANID NOT LIKE '%RWK%' AND STEPHANDLE NOT LIKE '%8888%' AND STEPHANDLE LIKE '%.%.%'
    group by lotid) a6

    where a5.lotid=a6.lotid 
    and a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.STEPHANDLE AND A5.EQPTYPE NOT IN ('CUDDFINP','CUBDFINP','BDFINP','DDFINP','CUDFSEM','DFSEM','SORT','CUSORT','CUNPURGE','NPURGE','EDFINP','CUEDFINP')

    group by a5.lotid
    order by a5.lotid
```

Output for first sql(the result is exactly what i wanted)

```
LOTID    STEPHANDLE
_____    ___________
S8CN9      214
S7JY7      30
 ...      .....
```

Second SQL

```
Select a5.lotid,a5.STEPHANDLE from 

(select lotid,COUNT(stephandle) as STEPHANDLE, EQPTYPE from LOTFLOW_D Group by lotid, EQPTYPE ) a5

left join

(select distinct(LOTID), MAX(STEPHANDLE) AS STEPHANDLE from Lotmove_R
where QTAP_GROUP In ('8685','8686','8687','8688','8689','8533','8532','2534','2533','8684','8690')
and datadate>sysdate-3
and priority<=5
and SUBPLANID NOT LIKE '%RWK%' AND STEPHANDLE NOT LIKE '%8888%' AND STEPHANDLE LIKE '%.%.%'
group by lotid) a6 on a5.lotid=a6.lotid

where a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.stephandle AND a5.EQPTYPE NOT IN ('CUDDFINP','CUBDFINP','BDFINP','DDFINP','CUDFSEM','DFSEM','SORT','CUSORT','CUNPURGE','NPURGE','EDFINP','CUEDFINP')

order by a5.lotid
```

The second one appeared error (invalid number for the max(stephandle)) as the value for
stephandle is something like this 1470.0.0400, i know this is not a number but it works perfectly using the first sql and that met my expected result( display in number), I tried count(stephandle) but the outcome is wrong and i need the second sql format to run on my main sql with left join

Comment: Your queries don't seem to make much sense. You want `lotmove.stephandle` to match `'%.%.%'`. Of these you take the maximum and compare it with a number (`count(stephandle)` from the other query) later. How can you possibly say whether 123 is greater or less than '12.34.56'?

Comment: On a sidenote: What do you expect `distinct(LOTID)` to do? First of all, `DISTINCT` is an operator for a row, so its `DISTINCT lotid, max(stephandle)` actually. Then, you are grouping by `lotid`, so every row is always distinct from the others anyway.

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove that distinct after i placed the group by

Comment: there are some rows with only one dot.  but that works on the first sql

Comment: Please **edit your post** and include the DDL for your tables and sample data which causes query #1 to work and query #2 to fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the first query you compare the stephandles

```
a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.STEPHANDLE
```

where the strings are compared alphabetically, e.g.

```
'1.2.3' < '2.3.4'
'1.2.3' > '10.0.0'
'1.2.3' > '1.2.04'
'1.2.3' > '1.2.20'
```

(As you say that your results are as expected, you have probably fixed length numbers. But then something like `where stephandle like '__.__.__'` would be more appropriate than `where stephandle like '%.%.%'`. And anyway, I'd expect this restriction on both tables, not just one.)

This comparision results in a number of matches per `lotid`, which you count with `COUNT(a5.stephandle) AS STEPHANDLE`. You could just as well use `COUNT(*)` of course, which would be more readable, because you are counting rows and don't want to detect null stephandles in order to exclude them from the count (this is what `COUNT(a5.stephandle)` does). Moreover the alias name `STEPHANDLE` is inappropriate, because it's not a stephandle you are showing in your result, but the number of stephandles, so `NUM_OF_STEPHANDLES` or `STEPHANDLE_COUNT` or `STEPHANDLES` would be much better names.

In your second query you count records per `lotid`, `eqptype` in your first query (again with `COUNT(stephandle)` which would better be `COUNT(*)`). This gives you numbers, e.g. 300, 1000, etc. Again you call this result `STEPHANDLE` which leads you to comparing

```
a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.stephandle
```

You probably wouldn't have done so with a better name, because

```
a5.STEPHANDLE_COUNT > a6.stephandle
```

obviously makes no sense.

What you really want, I can only guess. It seems you want to count how many `stephandles` per `lotid` in table `lotflow_d` have no higher counterpart in table `lotmove_r`. Something like this:

```
select lotid, count(*) as stephandles
from lotflow_d d
where eqptype not in ('CUDDFINP','CUBDFINP','BDFINP','DDFINP','CUDFSEM', 'DFSEM',
                      'SORT','CUSORT','CUNPURGE','NPURGE','EDFINP','CUEDFINP')
and not exists
(
  select *
  from lotmove_r r
  where r.lotid = d.lotid
    and r.stephandle >= d.stephandle
    and r.stephandle not like '%8888%'
    and r.stephandle like '%.%.%'
    and r.qtap_group in ('8685','8686','8687','8688','8689','8533',
                         '8532','2534','2533','8684','8690')
    and r.datadate > sysdate-3
    and r.priority <= 5
    and r.subplanid not like '%RWK%'
)
group by lotid
order by lotid;
```

Comment: you got my point, sorry for didnt express my problem precisely, you solved my problem, thanks alot! but can this be presented in left join format?

Comment: It can, but why would you want to do this? You want to count records in table `lotflow_d` under certain conditions. Conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause, not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i see, because my main formation of sql table using left join to join all the columns including this, and this is the last column left.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: oh, i mean i am using left join to join all the tables i have including this.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you still think you need a left outer join? If so, why?

Comment: Isnt it one left outer join can only use for one table? cause currently i am creating a daily report which involved the combination of 7 tables, including this, i used left outer join to join the other 5 tables, that's why for this one i need to use left outer join to combine also, can i include this in left outer join also? sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: You can use this query as a derived table (a subquery in the from clause) of a main query, such as `select * from sometable t left join ( <the query> ) q on q.lotid = t.lotid;` or `with q as ( <the query> ) select * from sometable t left join q on q.lotid = t.lotid;`.

Comment: okay, i try it on tomorrow and let you know the outcome, by the way thanks for the help!

Comment: done, it works on my code, thanks alot! by the way, i dont really understand this line 'and not exists'  in your code, do you mind explaning this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, I always considered `[NOT] EXISTS` self-explanatory. Well, let me try ... We read `lotflow_d` record by record. For each record we apply the `WHERE` clause in order to decide whether to keep the record or not. In the `NOT EXISTS` clause we say that we only keep the `lotflow_d` record, if not exists a `lotmove_r` record with the same `lotid` and a `stephandle` equal or greater (and `priority` <= 5 etc.). If such a record exists in `lotmove_r` we dismiss the `lotflow_d` record.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TO_CHAR as *TO_CHAR(COUNT (stephandle))* in your a5 query. That should later compare your values as strings, which is fine (it did the same in your first query).

I should just point out that referencing any of your a6 columns in where clause turns your left join into inner join. 
If you really want your query to act as left join, instead of

```
          ON a5.lotid = a6.lotid
WHERE     a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.stephandle
```

use:

```
ON (a5.lotid = a6.lotid AND a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.stephandle)
```

I also referenced that problem in some detail as answer to this question:
[Why can't you use OR or IN with a OUTER JOIN operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673246/why-cant-you-use-or-or-in-with-a-outer-join-operation/51673806#51673806)

Full code:

```
SELECT a5.lotid, a5.STEPHANDLE
FROM (  SELECT lotid, TO_CHAR (COUNT (stephandle)) AS STEPHANDLE, EQPTYPE
          FROM LOTFLOW_D
      GROUP BY lotid, EQPTYPE) a5
     LEFT JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT (LOTID), MAX (STEPHANDLE) AS STEPHANDLE
                    FROM Lotmove_R
                   WHERE     QTAP_GROUP IN ('8685',
                                            '8686',
                                            '8687',
                                            '8688',
                                            '8689',
                                            '8533',
                                            '8532',
                                            '2534',
                                            '2533',
                                            '8684',
                                            '8690')
                         AND datadate > SYSDATE - 3
                         AND priority <= 5
                         AND SUBPLANID NOT LIKE '%RWK%'
                         AND STEPHANDLE NOT LIKE '%8888%'
                         AND STEPHANDLE LIKE '%.%.%'
                GROUP BY lotid) a6
         ON (a5.lotid = a6.lotid AND a5.STEPHANDLE > a6.stephandle)
WHERE a5.EQPTYPE NOT IN ('CUDDFINP',
                         'CUBDFINP',
                         'BDFINP',
                         'DDFINP',
                         'CUDFSEM',
                         'DFSEM',
                         'SORT',
                         'CUSORT',
                         'CUNPURGE',
                         'NPURGE',
                         'EDFINP',
                         'CUEDFINP')
ORDER BY a5.lotid
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion but the outcome same as the second sql (by using count)

Comment: @kit Is it still reporting invalid number error after using TO_CHAR (COUNT (stephandle)) ? At what point in code? (I've now edited my answer to show full code)

Comment: Hi, Thorsten Kettner have actually explained something that i didnt mentioned in my post, thanks for your effort and sorry for the inconvenience caused.